# how to remove username field from login page in django userchangeform

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

#### there are three fields in login page(username,email,password) but i want only two fields(email,password). how to remove username field from login page. thanks in advance

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username','email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

> serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Remove field `username` from login endpoint

You can remove the field `username` by overriding the `LoginSerializer` like this:

```py
from rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer as RestAuthLoginSerializer


class LoginSerializer(RestAuthLoginSerializer):
    username = None
```

And then adding following in your `settings.py`:

```py
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.your.LoginSerializer'}

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

---

### Add an endpoint to change email and password

It turned out that this actually was not the question of the OP but I leave it here for completeness.

You can add an endpoint to change the users settings like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers, generics
from . import models


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password')


class UserChangeView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

By the way, you don't need the forms for your API.

Comment: yes there are normally two fields(username , password) and its working perfect but when i try to login by providing email,password and leave username empty then i get an error ( "Must include \"username\" and \"password\"." ). is there any way to login with just email and password ?

Comment: @MuhammadHussnain You are right, I'm using a custom login serializer and I wasn't aware that the default one has three fields. I updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Actually i am newbie in DRF. I defined LoginSerializer in serializers.py and replace { 'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.your.LoginSerializer' } to { 'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.serializers.LoginSerializer'} but now i am getting error ( No module named 'path' )

Comment: No problem. `'path.to.your.LoginSerializer'` has to be the complete import path. For instance if your Django app (the folder where your `models.py` is inside) is called `myapp` then your setting has to look like this: `{ 'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'myapp.serializers.LoginSerializer' }`.

Comment: For some reason this custom Login isn't working for me. When I goto the url on a browser Username is still there.